# Уменьшить погрешность функции при разложении на степенной ряд

Tags: java, netbeans

Есть рабочая прога, вычисляющая значение функции через разложение на степенной ряд. Однако у меня выходит слишком большая погрешность (~0,075), подскажите как её можно уменьшить.

Условия задания:
Для х изменяющегося от a до b с шагом (b-a)/k, где (k=10), вычислить функцию f(x), используя ее разложение в степенной ряд в трех случаях:

а) для заданного n;

б) для заданной точности e (e=0.0001);

с) для «точного» значения (по аналитической формуле).

Для сравнения найти относительную погрешность вычисления функции значение функции
  о_погр = ABS(  (точ_знач – приближ_знач)/ точ_знач)

```
package tk.lab3;

public class TkLab3 {
//Функция с установленным N  
public static double SummN (double endN, double x) 
{ 
    double summ = 1, n = 0, currnumb, xb = x, factorialb = 1, fact = 1, Z;
    do { 
        n++; 
        Z = Math.cos(n*Math.PI/4);
        currnumb = xb * Z / factorialb; 
        factorialb *= ++fact;            
        xb *= x; 
        summ += currnumb;
    }while (n<endN);
    return summ; 
} 

//Функция  с установленной точностью 
public static double SummE (double e, double x) 
{ 
    double summ = 1, currnumb = 0, prevnumb, xb = x, factorialb = 1, factorial = 1, Z, k=0; 
    do
    { 
        k++;
        Z = Math.cos(k*Math.PI/4);
        prevnumb = currnumb;  
        currnumb = Z * xb / factorialb; 
        factorialb *= ++factorial; 
        xb *= x;
        summ += currnumb; 
    } while (Math.abs(currnumb - prevnumb) >= e); 
    return summ; 
} 

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
   double xn = 0.1, xk = 1, dx = (xk-xn)/10, eps = 0.0001, x, n = 25, y,     summN, summE; 
   System.out.println("X - параметр;\nSummN - суммы для заданного n;\nSummE     - суммы для заданной точности;\nY - точное значение функции;\nпогрешность SummN,     погрешность SummE – относительные погрешности приближенных вычислений.\nn =     "+n+"\n"); 
   for (x = xn; (x <= xk) && (x >= 0.1); x += dx) 
   { 
// Использование функции расчета значения с заданным n: 
       summN = SummN(n,x); 
// Использование функции расчета значения с заданной точностью:
       summE = SummE(eps,x); 
// Расчет условно точного значения: 
       y = Math.pow(Math.E,x*Math.cos(Math.PI/4))*x*Math.sin(Math.PI/4); 
       System.out.println(String.format("X = %f; SummN = %.15f; SummE = %.15f; Y = %.15f; погрешность SummN = %.15f; погрешность SummE = %.15f;", x, summN, summE, y, Math.abs((y-summN)/y), Math.abs((y-summE)/y))); 
   }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось просто ошибся в точном значении функции: e^(x*cos(pi/4))*cos(x*sin(pi/4))